# notify-send messages sent from a systemd unit delayed

Tags: linux, systemd, notifications, lock-screen, dunst

There's an active systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch the screenlock daemon service
PartOf=graphical-session.target
After=i3wm.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=env screenlock-daemon
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

that starts the daemon script `screenlock-daemon`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xss-lock --session="${XDG_SESSION_ID}" --ignore-sleep --notifier=notifier --transfer-sleep-lock -- my-locking-command
```

As per [xss-lock](https://man.archlinux.org/man/xss-lock.1.en), prior to locking it notifies user by running the `notifier` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "executing at $(date +%R:%S)" >> /tmp/screenlock-notifier-exec  # message is logged at 
                                                                     # the expected time.
notify-send --urgency=normal --expire-time=10000 -- 'Locking screen soon...'
```

Problem is, the notification pop-up is shown with a multi-second delay. Only if a manual notify-send command is sent, it's shown immediately.

Is this something to do with how systemd works, or maybe it's the notification daemon I'm using - [dunst](https://github.com/dunst-project/dunst)?

---

Running debian testing.